# fastapi extract all path parameter key and value

Tags: python, fastapi

Is there a way that I can extract the key-value pair of the optional path parameter?

lets say that I have the following code:

```
@app.get("/users")
async def request(userEmail = None, organization = None):
```

and I send the get request to the following url:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/users?userEmail=test@test.com&organization=testOrg

Is there a way that I can extract the key-value pair of the optional path parameter so that I can get

```
{"userEmail" : "test@test.com", "organization" : "testOrg"}
```

Or if http://127.0.0.1:8000/users?userEmail=test@test.com,
then

```
{"userEmail" : "test@test.com"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Request object, from starlette library

```py
from fastapi import Request


@app.get("/users")
async def users(request: Request,
                userEmail = None, organization = None):
    print(request.query_params)
```

Query parameters are exposed as an immutable multi-dict.

reference https://www.starlette.io/requests/#query-parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can use **request.query_params._dict** it will extract in key-value pairs.

```
from fastapi import Request


@app.get("/users")
async def users(request: Request,
                userEmail = None, organization = None):
    print(request.query_params._dict)
```

if you hit request: http://127.0.0.1:8000/users?userEmail=test@test.com&organization=testOrg

it will give you `{"userEmail":"test@test.com","organization":"testOrg"}`